# Download file with C# WindowsForms "WebBrowser" from Sharepoint OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web, browsers

When I looking for way to communicate with Sharepoint OneDrive, I can't understand cridentials and way to login with c# desktop app. And I found another way. 
I create WebBrowser component, then

```
WebBrowser.URI = new URI ("my sharepoint site").
```

and get Authorization page. Write my login and password and after that i can create another webBrowser object and get information about file, methadata, information about directories and forders.

But, I can't find way for download file. 
I have link of download my file.

```
https://mysite-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myuser_onmicrosoft_com/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/personal/myuser_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Shared with Everyone/testExcel.xlsx')/$value.
```

When I paste this link in desktopBrowser (like a Google Chrome), bwowser automaticaly download this file on my PC.

And there is queston: How can I do this with .Net WindowsForms WebBrowser component.

I did "WebBrowser.URI = new URI ("my link for download file")." and event WebBrowser.FileDownload is called. But i can't find, where my file was downloaded. 
It's really downloaded? Or maybe I need to use another way?
Thanks

Comment: i am also stucked in same issue can anybody help please.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this with the DownloadFile (sync or async) method of the WebClient class:

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
        wc.DownloadFile(urlOfFile, localFileName);
    }
```

You can specify credentials or set WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true.  If you want to download the file asynchronously, use [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.